# How to extend the event/occurrence models in django-scheduler

Tags: django, django-models, django-scheduler

I'd like to augment events/occurrences in [django-scheduler](https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler/tree/0.8.6) with three things:

- Location
- Invitees
- RSVPs

For Location, my initial thought was to subclass Event and add Location as a foreign key to a Location class, but my assumption is that each occurrence saved won't then include Location, so if the location changes for one occurrence, I'll have nowhere to store that information.

In this situation, is it recommended to create an EventRelation instead? Will I then be able to specify a different Location for one occurrence in a series? The EventRelation solution seems untidy to me, I'd prefer to keep models in classes for clarity and simplicity.

I think Invitees is the same problem, so presumably I should use a similar solution?

For RSVPs, I intend to make an RSVP class with Occurrence as a foreign key, and as far as I can tell that should work without any issues as long as I save the occurrence before attaching it to an RSVP?

I've read all the docs, all the GitHub issues, various StackOverflow threads, the tests, the model source, etc, but it's still unclear what the "right" way to do it is.

I found a PR which introduces abstract models: https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler/pull/389 which looks like exactly what I want, but I'm reluctant to use code which was seemingly abandoned 18 months ago as I won't get the benefit of future improvements.

**EDIT:** I'm now thinking that another way to do this would be to have just one object linked to the event using EventRelation, so I'd have an "EventDetails" object connected to the Event via EventRelation, then include FKs to Location, Guests, etc from that object.

I should then also be able to subclass my EventDetails object with different kinds of events and attach those too. I'll give it a go ant see if it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone find this and is wondering the same thing: I ended up ditching Django-scheduler and using Django-recurrence instead. Had to do a bit more work myself, but it was easier to create the custom event types that I was looking for. Worked pretty well!